# <label> at the top of a td without moving the td next to it?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="blah.png" width="80"> </td>
        <td> <p>This is ment to be a comment section part</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is meant to be a comment engine kind of a thing.

Basically, I want a table with a profile image first on the left. Then I want the username at the very top of the TD, then the comment *below* the name without the name pushing it forward.
Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with the `<label>` tag you mentioned in your subject line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not quite clear what you’re asking. Does the following HTML not achieve what you’re trying to do?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="blah.png" width="80"></td>
        <td>
            <p>Username</p>
            <p>This is ment to be a comment section part</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Edit:**

Facebook’s comments look like this: [image: Facebook comments]

I can see two differences between that and the code I posted above:

1. Facebook has the username aligned with the top of the image
2. Facebook has the username on the same line as the comment.

Issue 1 can be taken care of by assigning `vertical-align: top` to all the cells in the table. Issue 2 could be handled with [`display: run-in`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visuren.html#run-in), but that’s not supported in Firefox or IE 7 and 6, so you’re better off just having the username and comment be inline elements:

```
<table class="comment">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="blah.png" width="80" height="80"></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Username</strong>: <span>This is ment to be a comment section part</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hK85e/2/

Comment: Not really. Sorry im not being clear. What I ment was. Name at the top of the table next to the image and the coment below. The Username would be right next to the comment otherwise.I want it like Facebook has it.

Comment: you mean you want the image and the username in the same row (next to each other), and in the row below the comment aligned with the username? did you try Paul's answer? (img should be valigned top)

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer: I’m still not really clear what you’re describing, but I’ve popped in a screenshot from Facebook and a JSFiddle for you to have a look at.

Comment: Sorry, still not it. Im not very good at explaining. I want it like Facebook has theirs.

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer: That’s okay. Could you explain *how* my second example differs from the Facebook screenshot I included?

Comment: Ugh sorry. Im not with it tonight! I havent gotten much sleep. Thought Facebook had a different layout to that. Although I like that anyway. So Il stick with that. thanks alot.